# Install fancyInput plugin to website

Tags: jquery, css, html, sass

I checked out the fancyInput plugin but i don't get how i should install it to my website.
I checked out the github project but don't realize how to install it.

Is there an page or blog that shows how to install it ?

Comment: Which fancyInput plugin.. Show us what have you tried...?

Answer (score 0):

check this and follow the instructions

http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-for-Typing-In-Input-with-Amazing-CSS3-Effects-Fancy-Input.html

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. You can try for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dropthebit.com/demos/fancy_input/styles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dropthebit.com/demos/fancy_input/fancyInput.css" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='http://dropthebit.com/demos/fancy_input/fancyInput.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('#myInput').fancyInput();
            });
        </script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="myInput" type='text' value="Hello!" style="border:solid 1px gray;" />
    </body>
</html>
```